# TypeError: X is not a constructor when module exports

Tags: node.js

I found [this](https://github.com/dsandor/dymojs/blob/master/lib/index.js) npm package online which is no longer maintained. The package uses

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = Dymo;
} else {
    window.Dymo = Dymo;
}
```

at the end to export a Dymo class. Now I wanted to change a few things on this code, so I decided to copy this and make some changes but stored is as a local js file.

So instead of calling Dymo as

```
const Dymo = require('dymojs');
```

I tried doing

```
const Dymo = require('./dymojs')
```

But when I do:

```
let dymo = new Dymo();
```

I get

> TypeError: Dymo is not a constructor

Comment: You will have to show us more code so we can see what Dymo actually is.  Please show us your modified dymojs file.  Also, did you install `node-fetch` locally. That's a dependent file which will need to be installed locally since you changed where the index.js file is located.

Comment: In addition, the dymojs module on NPM doesn't contain a dymojs file.  It contains an index.js file.  So, please show us EXACTLY what you changed and what you copied locally and why you're trying to do `require('./dymojs')` when there is no `dymojs.js` file.

Comment: For the start I just wanted to see if I could copy and use it, so I created a file at the root of my project called `dymo.js`. Vscode autocompletes my path so I now my path is correct. The content of the file is the same as the the index.js file that can be found on Github. I did not copy anything else besides that. I just copied the `index.js` file contents to `dymo.js` file I created. I also installed `node-fetch` locally

Comment: Well, if you look in that file, it includes other libraries and those are perhaps not loading properly.  To make an independent copy, you would need to install those locally.